# Php upload file yields error code 4. Why?

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

The HTML:

```
<form action="formhandler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and doing a `print_r($_FILES)` in formhandler.php after choosing a file and clicking submit yields:

```
[file] => Array
    (
        [name] => 
        [type] => 
        [tmp_name] => 
        [error] => 4
        [size] => 0
    )
```

And error code 4, according to the manual stands for "UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE - No file was uploaded" but I can't figure out why it wasn't uploaded.

Comment: Could be to do with your tmp folder? Does PHP have the right permissions?

Comment: @JoshuaSmickus Hmm maybe. Where is this temp folder? I know there is a temporary upload before you handle it properly with move_uploaded_file(). Is it the folder where formhandler.php is in?

Comment: Print_r($_FILES); return the complete information of file please make sure your uploading file and the event call on button submit

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In this case, the problem was: I had multiple input elements with the attribute `name="image"`. When I changed to individual names the error disappeared.

Comment: Hello. Is it possible for you to ellaborate more on this? I have the same error and I think is the same cause, but I'm not understanding what you mean to "changed to individual names". Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RaRdEvA Hi. What I meant was that I gave all my <input> a unique name attribute. Before I had name="image" for several inputs. Then I changed it so that no <input> had the same name="" attribute as anything else. That's what I meant with "individual names". I made the name attributes unique.

Comment: That clarifies a lot. I thought you meant to give that name in the PHP code and I never thought it was in the HTML. I solved it by changing the name of what was received before it was uploaded. Thanks again, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Other solution (PHP 7.3.11)

for answer @Weblurk https://stackoverflow.com/a/21698740/9635711

Don't works:

```
<input id="files" multiple="true" name="file_images_send[header_image]" type="file">
<input id="files" multiple="true" name="file_images_send[header_image]" type="file">
```

It works - Solution - with array "[]" end name input

```
<input id="files" multiple="true" name="file_images_send[header_image][]" type="file">
<input id="files" multiple="true" name="file_images_send[header_image][]" type="file">
```

Comment: I started getting this error after I removed the "[]" from the name. The error is what brought me to this page.

Answer (score 0):

These may happen when you upload multiple pictures and the device is a phone; because sometimes phones save the file with same name under different folders; but, in the upload, you get the same file in the same folder with the same name, thus, leaving you without files.

What I did is to change the name before the upload, in PHP, to grant a unique name to each file. Error is gone now.

This is not the solution, just a solution for a specific situation in the same circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

My issue for this error was having multiple forms in an index view (each row having a separate form of inputs of the same name) and the forms falsely sharing the same id.

Once I removed the forms id the issue was resolved.